# Selecting values in a dataframe based on a priority list

Tags: r

I am new to R so am still getting my head around the way it works. My problem is as follows, I have a data frame and a prioritised list of columns (`pl`), I need:

1. To find the maximum value from the columns in `pl` for each row and create a new column with this value (`df$max`)
2. Using the priority list, subtract this maximum value from the priority value, ignoring NAs and returning the absolute difference

Probably better with an example:
My priority list is

```
pl <- c("E","D","A","B")
```

and the data frame is:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   
1   15  5   20  9   NA  6   1   
2   3   2   NA  5   1   3   2   
3   NA  NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  
4   0   1   0   7   8   NA  6
5   1   2   3   NA  NA  1   6
```

So for the first line the maximum is from column A (15) and the priority value is from column D (9) since E is a NA. The answer I want should look like this.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   MAX MAX-PR
1   15  5   20  9   NA  6   1   15  6
2   3   2   NA  5   1   3   2   5   4
3   NA  NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4   0   1   0   7   8   NA  6   8   0
5   1   2   3   NA  NA  1   6   2   1
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
df$MAX <- apply(df[,pl], 1, max, na.rm = T)
df$MAX_PR <- df$MAX - apply(df[,pl], 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
df$MAX[is.infinite(df$MAX)] <- NA
> df

#    A  B  C  D  E  F  G MAX MAX_PR
# 1 15  5 20  9 NA  6  1  15      6
# 2  3  2 NA  5  1  3  2   5      4
# 3 NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA  NA     NA
# 4  0  1  0  7  8 NA  6   8      0
# 5  1  2  3 NA NA  1  6   2      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,NA,2,5,3,1),B=c(3,5,NA,6,NA,10),C=c(NA,3,4,5,1,4))
pl <- c("B","A","C")
#now we find the maximum per row, ignoring NAs
max.per.row <- apply(df,1,max,na.rm=T)
#and the first element according to the priority list, ignoring NAs
#(there may be a more efficient way to do this)
first.per.row <- apply(df[,pl],1, function(x) as.vector(na.omit(x))[1])
#and finally compute the difference
max.less.first.per.row <- max.per.row - first.per.row
```

Note that this code will break for any row that is all NA. There is no check against that.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple version. First , I take only pl columns , for each line I remove na then I compute the max.

```
 df <- dat[,pl]
 cbind(dat, t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
                      x <- na.omit(x)
                      c(max(x),max(x)-x[1])
                    }
                )
              )
       )


   A  B  C  D  E  F  G    1  2
1 15  5 20  9 NA  6  1   15  6
2  3  2 NA  5  1  3  2    5  4
3 NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA -Inf NA
4  0  1  0  7  8 NA  6    8  0
5  1  2  3 NA NA  1  6    2  1
```